# Storm Drpc Heap issue

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am trying to make a call to a remote Drpc server that would execute my function on a running topology.

The client returns the following errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:140)
  at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
  at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
  at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
  at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
  at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
  at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
  at backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$Client.recv_execute(DistributedRPC.java:75)
  at backtype.storm.generated.DistributedRPC$Client.execute(DistributedRPC.java:61)
  at backtype.storm.utils.DRPCClient.execute(DRPCClient.java:41)
  at smile.util.DrpcDriver.main(DrpcDriver.java:26)
  ... 6 more
```

1) Topology is active:

```
exclamation          ACTIVE     10         3            175
```

2) drpc server/daemon is running backtype.storm.daemon.drpc

3) storm .yaml has the following options:

```
worker.childopts: " -Xmx768m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError "
drpc.servers: "<name of my host>"
```

`storm.yaml` has one host, one port configured.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case of wrong configuration of xmx.i remember a semi column between xmx and 768m.
please see this doc.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: thats not the case  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms